# Displaying UDP Multicast Rawvideo Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, java, udp, opencv

I have a problem while trying to capture the raw video over UDP.
In my setup, I stream the webcam with FFmpeg (command line) via UDP, on the client side I use Java OpenCV, the capture line; `VideoCapture.open("udp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx)`

If I sent the stream with mpegts (`ffmpeg -f mpegts`), I can display the stream but if I sent it as rawvideo (`ffmpeg -f rawvideo`),I couldn't.

Server Side:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0"  -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f rawvideo udp://236.0.0.1:2000`

Client (OpenCV Java);

`VideoCapture.open("udp://@236.0.0.1:2000");`

Is there any parameter to set (like CvType) ?

Comment: Answered at your crosspost: [Displaying UDP Multicast Rawvideo Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60902660/displaying-udp-multicast-rawvideo-stream). Did you know you can [merge your two accounts](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I created a SDP file for the UDP stream and call it from open() method;

```
VideoCapture.open("test.sdp");
```

Thats all.